# VHDL: Assigning elements from a 2D array to 1D array

Tags: vhdl, register-transfer-level

I have a 2D array of records which I have to select column by column for processing. I am marshaling the column records into a *column array*, something like this:

```
col_array(0) <= ( td_array(0)(0), td_array(1)(0), td_array(2)(0), td_array(3)(0) );
```

Essentially an array append operation.

I have several arrays like this. Is this possible to do with a for-generate loop ?

This looks like an array append kind of operation. How do you do this ?

---

Addenda:
Each record in the 2D array looks like:

```
type foo is record:
  enable : std_logic;
  index  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  cmd    : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
end record;
```

So I will have interfaces like these in a row-column arrangement:

```
30  31  32
20  21  22   
10  11  12
00  01  02
```

I will need to break-out the record signals by the column (using a multiplexer). So (00, 10, 20, 30) will be accessed on the output of a MUX.

Comment: Can you post more code with your data types - that looks like a vector of vectors, not a 2-d array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure of the actual usage you are looking for (how does the index of `col_array` relate to the indices of `td_array` if at all), but does this help?  (I've rearranged things as a [2-d array](http://parallelpoints.com/node/65) rather than a vector of vectors)

```
architecture a1 of test is
    type std_ulogic_2d is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_ulogic;
    signal td_array : std_ulogic_2d(0 to 3, 0 to 4);
    signal col_array : std_ulogic_vector(td_array'range(1));
begin  -- architecture a1
    iloop : for i in td_array'range(1) generate
        col_array(i) <= td_array(i,0);
    end generate;
end architecture a1;
```